# The Grassmannian Gr(2,8) and an E7 surprise

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, string-theory, supersymmetry, exceptional-groups

Are there any mathematical explanations for the following surprising facts?
$$\int_{Gr(2,8)} c_{\text{top}}(TX(-2)) = 6556 = \frac{1}{2} \deg(E_7/P(\alpha_7)) + 1,$$
and
$$\int_{Gr(2,6)} c_{\text{top}}(TX(-2)) = 143 = \frac{1}{2} \deg(\mathbb{S}_{12}).$$
where $\mathbb{S}_{12}$ is the spinor variety of type $D_6.$
The homogeneous varieties $E_7/P(\alpha_7)$ and $\mathbb{S}_{12}$ appear in Landsberg-Manivel's spaces subexceptional series.

Related surprises appear in supersymmetric gauge theories studied by Dimofte and Gaiotto.

Added (Dec 2018):
$$\int_{Gr(2,5)} c_{\text{top}}(TX(-2)) = 22 = \frac{1}{2} \deg(Gr(3,6)) + 1.$$

Comment: 6556 is a little too large to make that seem likely.

Comment: The subexceptional series is $\mathrm{LG}(3,6)$, $\mathrm{Gr}(3,6)$, $\mathbb{S}_{12}$ and $\mathrm{E}_7/P_7$. I believe that, related to this question, is the fundamental relation:$$ \frac{1}{10} \left( \frac{1}{2} \deg \mathrm{E}_7/P_7 - 2 + \frac{1}{2} \deg \mathbb{S}_{12} - 2 - \frac{1}{2} \deg \mathrm{Gr}(3,6) - 2 - \frac{1}{2} \deg \mathrm{LG}(3,6) - 2 \right) = 666$$

Comment: I don't know notation $E_7/P(\alpha_7)$ - which of the symmetric spaces it is using Cartan notation - see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space ? In $EIII$ we have naturally embedded grassmanian $G_{2,8}$. In $EVI$ we have naturally embedded grassmanian $G_{2,10}$. They can be considered as 1-dimensional projective spaces over $\mathbb C\otimes \mathbb O$ and $\mathbb H\otimes \mathbb O$

Comment: Sorry I made mistake above. Please replace $G_{2,10}$ with $G_{4,8}$ in my previoius comment. These are oriented grassmanians. So for example $G_{1,8}$ is sphere $S^8$. Normally $+$ sign is added for oriented grassmanian. Grassmanian $G_{2,6}^+$ is quotient $SO_8/U_4$. Namely it is set of complex structures on $R^8$.